# Fastest way to select a line of standard out text in iterm2

Tags: stdout, copy-paste, iterm2, iterm

I have to copy text from a program that outputs it to the screen. I have to do this repeatedly many times.

Using the trackpad on my mac and copy paste with my left hand, I am pretty fast, but invariably, the lengths of lines and line wrapping cause problems/frustration like accidentally selecting too much or too little.

I desire a single action to select and copy an entire line in one or two movements (eg. click line, press shortcut key).

I have discovered that a line can be copied using ["copy mode"](https://iterm2.com/documentation-copymode.html) using the following sequence of actions:

1. double click verse number (to set the cursor position)
2. enter copy mode (shift+cmd+c)
3. press shift+5 ($) to select entire line
4. press cntrl+k to copy the line

[image]

Can these four commands be combined into a single action (or at least combine steps 2, 3, and 4 into a single key stroke)?

Or, perhaps, is there another way to copy a single line efficiently?